# AngularJS $promise then() data undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource, angular-promise

I am trying to get data assigned to a $scope variable. Inside my $promise.then() function it is displaying correctly but outside the function it shows as undefined. The following is my controller code:

```
angular.module('testSiteApp').controller('TestController', function ($scope, Tests) { 

$scope.test = Tests.get({id: 1});

$scope.test.$promise.then(function(data) {
    $scope.tasks = data.tasks;
    console.log($scope.tasks);
});

console.log($scope.tasks); 

});
```

The results inside the then() function:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

The results outside the then() function:

```
undefined
```

The 'Tests' service factory I am using is the following:

```
angular.module('testSiteApp').factory('Tests', function($resource) {

return $resource('/api/test/:id', {id: '@id'}, { 'update': { method: 'PUT' } } );

});
```

Even when I use the query method instead of the get for my resource and set isArray to true I still end up with the same issue. For some reason the data is not binding to my scope inside the then function.

I am sorry if this is a repeat question but i looked everywhere and only found undefined issue relating to the $promise function which is no the issue in this case.

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 13):

The function passed to `.then()` will be called after the data has been fetched from the backend. The other `console.log()` (the one outside of `.then()`) will be called **immediately after the request has been made**, and **not after it has been completed**, thus the `tasks` is undefined.

Consider the timing (of course times are only an example):

```
// time = 0.000 sec. You make a request to the backend
$scope.test = Tests.get({id: 1});

$scope.test.$promise.then(function(data) {
    // time = 1.000 sec. Request is completed. 
    // data is available, so you assign it to $scope.tasks
    $scope.tasks = data.tasks;
    console.log($scope.tasks);
});

// time = 0.000 sec (!!!) This has been called NOT AFTER
// the callback, but rather immediately after the Tests.get()
// So the data is not available here yet.
console.log($scope.tasks);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a promise so it sets $scope.task **after** it returns.  Until that return occurs $scope.task is undefined, which is what your second console.log is showing .  At some later time the promise is resolved (completes) and $scope.task has a value, which is what your first console.log shows.

Comment: I understand the problem, but how do you make the scope wait? or is this just bad code?

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.test.$promise.then(function(data) {

if(data){    
$scope.tasks = data.tasks;
}

console.log($scope.tasks);
});
```

try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to fetch data and resolve with promise, please note fetch data will only work after then call...

```
getData(){
      const promise = this.httpClient.get(this.PHP_API_SERVER+'/api/books').toPromise();  
      promise.then((data)=>{
        console.log("Resolved: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        return JSON.stringify(data);
      }, (error)=>{
        console.log("Rejected " + JSON.stringify(error));
      })
    }
```